# Non-repeated arrays in a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, unique, non-repetitive

I am looking for non-repeated rows in a matrix.

Assume:

A =

```
 8     1
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 3     6
 5     7
 5     7
```

I would like to get "B" which is:

B=

```
 8     1
 3     6
```

Please mind **C=unique(A,'rows')** will give us unique rows of "A" which include repeated and non-repeated arrays and only remove repetitious rows. It means:

C =

```
 2     2
 3     6
 5     7
 8     1
```

"C" is not the one that I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second and third outputs of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) as follows:

```
[~, ii, jj] = unique(A,'rows');
kk = find(histc(jj,unique(jj))==1);
B = A(sort(ii(kk)),:);
```

Or use this more direct [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)-based approach:

```
B = A(sum(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A.', permute(A, [2 3 1])))))==1,:);
```

These two approaches work in quite generally: `A` may have any number of columns, and may contain non-integer values.

---

If `A` always has two columns and contains only integer values, you can also do it with [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html), using the sparse option (sixth input argument) to save memory in case of large values:

```
[ii jj] = find(accumarray(A, 1, [], @sum, 0, true)==1);
B = [ii jj];
```

Or you can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) instead of `accumarray`:

```
[ii jj] = find(sparse(A(:,1),A(:,2),1)==1);
B = [ii jj];
```

Comment: Think you can save on the transpose in the bsxfun approach - `A(sum(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(A, [3 2 1])),2)))==1,:)` +1 of course for that :)

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! You're right. But saving that `.'` introduces one `,2`. I tend to prefer `.'`. Besides, it may serve to call people's attention on [the meaning of `.'`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23510668/2586922)

Comment: haha cheeky that one! So trying to avoid sum(..,2), is that a performance thing? Because there must be some overhead for transpose, but is sum(..,2) over sum() greater than that overheard? I have no idea about the performance variations on these.

Comment: @Divakar Summing along cols is faster that summing along rows or higher dims. I'm pretty sure about that. And the reason is Matlab stores arrays in column-major order. But the savings should balanced against the time needed to do the transpose.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of the rows, try this -

```
[C,~,ic] = unique(A,'rows','legacy')
B = C(histc(ic,unique(ic))==1,:)
```