# MATLAB: create a large matrix by repeating elements of a vector, with increasing stride for each column

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, repeat

In MATLAB I have a vector x of length n, where n is usually O(10), and I would like to build a tall matrix A of size [n^m,m], where m is again 0(10). The matrix has a peculiar form: if n=4 and m=6,  let

```
x=[x1; x2; x3; x4]
```

then A is

```
   x1 x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x2 x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x3 x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x4 x1 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x1 x2 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x2 x2 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x3 x2 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x4 x2 x1 x1 x1 x1
   x1 x3 x2 x1 x1 x1
   .               .         
   .               . 
   .               .
   x4 x4 x4 x4 x4 x4
```

In practice, each column is obtained by repeating the elements of x, with an increasing stride for each column. How can I do that? If possible, I'd prefer an efficient (vectorized) solution, because, as you can see, the number of rows of A increases exponentially with m.

EDIT: whoops, sorry! I forgot I also need to build a vector V of size [n^m,1], based on vector w having the same length of x

```
w=[w1; w2; w3; w4]
```

V is

```
   w1^6
   w2*w1^5
   w3*w1^5
     .
     .
     .
   w4^6
```

Hope the crappy graphics is clear enough. Anyway, V is a  column vector of lenght n^m. Guess I could create a matrix B from w, in the same way one creates a matrix A from x, and then use prod(B,2)?

Comment: [This question, and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895335/2586922), may help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`allcomb tool from MATLAB file-exchange`](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb)** to generate the possible combinations of  the indices `[1 2 3 4]` and then use them to index into `x` -

```
v = repmat({1:numel(x)},1,m);
A = x(fliplr(allcomb(v{:})));
```

Also, it seems instead of using `fliplr`, you can use - `allcomb(v{:},'matlab')` instead.

For the edited part of the question, you can use a modified version of it -

```
V = prod(x(allcomb(v{:})),2)
```

## Benchmarking

Please note that these are for runnable solutions posted here.

**Benchmarking Code**

```
%// Parameters and input x
n = 10; m = 6;num_runs = 20; x =  randi(9,n,1);

disp('-------- With allcomb')
tic
for runs = 1:num_runs
    v = repmat({1:numel(x)},1,m);
    A = x(fliplr(allcomb(v{:})));
end
toc,    clear v A

disp('-------- With bsxfun')
tic
for runs = 1:num_runs
    A = x(floor(mod(bsxfun(@rdivide, (0:n^m-1).', n.^[0:m-1] ), n)+1)); %//'
end
toc,    clear A

disp('-------- With ttable')
tic
for runs = 1:num_runs
    I = ttable(n*ones(1,m));
    A = x(I);
end
toc,    clear I A

disp('-------- With arrayfun')
tic
for runs = 1:num_runs
    A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)...
        (repmat(reshape(repmat(x',n^(i-1),1),[],1),n^(m-i),1)),1:m,'uni',0));
end
toc
```

**Results**

```
-------- With allcomb
Elapsed time is 6.544981 seconds.
-------- With bsxfun
Elapsed time is 11.547062 seconds.
-------- With ttable
Elapsed time is 15.729932 seconds.
-------- With arrayfun
Elapsed time is 4.319048 seconds.
```

Comment: @Divakar, allcomb seems fast! Also, it builds an index matrix, which may be useful for vector V (see my edit, and apologies if I forgot to write it before!). I will try it out. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @DeltaIV Exactly! Just use that index array and then use `prod` for the edit part - `prod(fliplr(allcomb(v,v,v,v,v,v)),2)` I think (Not tested). In fact you don't need to use `fliplr` then! Good luck!

Comment: @Divakar, Ouch! I have an issue, though...m (the number of dimensions) is a parameter in my code. So I cannot hardcode `allcomb(x,x,x,x,x,x)` in my code, because I have no idea how many copies of x's I will need to multiply, until runtime! Is there a solution?

Comment: @DeltaIV Check out the edited code! Good call on that, now it's generic! Also incorporated the solution to the EDIT into the solution.

Comment: @Divakar Great! BTW,  `allcomb` has an argument `matlab` which makes the first column change fastest,so using  `allcomb(v{:},'matlab')` I got rid of the call to  `fliplr`.

Comment: @DeltaIV WOW!! Awesomeness in that tool! So you are all set it seems! :)

Answer (score 4):

One-liner based only on built-in functions (namely, [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) and the very powerful [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)):

```
result = x(floor(mod(bsxfun(@rdivide, (0:n^m-1).', n.^[0:m-1] ), n)+1));
```

Comment: This should be the fastest one. (I have been looking for your answer and here it is!)

Comment: @Yvon :-) Yes, it's vectorized and looks efficient, so it should be very fast. In fact, I was thinking about doing some benchmarking... but most other answers involve downloading functions and I can't be bothered

Comment: @LuisMendo Posted some benchmarking results in my solution.

Comment: Don't understand what it does, but respect is due for one-liners using bsxfun! +1

Comment: @LuisMendo Something with `bsxfun and @rdivide..`. You have my +1 too!

Comment: @DeltaIV `bsxfun` applies an operation to different combinations of values spread along different dimensions. Try `bsxfun(@plus, [1 2 3], [10 20].')` to grasp what it does (note the transpose in the second vector)

Comment: @LuisMendo,  thanks a lot for the answer! I know that `bsxfun` is used to apply an operation between two different-sized arrays, expanding them if needed. I still don't get the meaning of your one-liner. For starters, why the dot in `(0:n^m-1).'`? `(0:n^m-1)'` seems to generate the same vector. Why the `mod` function? If you used `ceil` instead of `floor`, would that get rid of the two -1? The main problem for me is that I don't understand what the code is doing.

Comment: @LuisMendo `.'` is transpose, whereas `'` is conjugate transpose. See a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922). `mod` is applied to get only numbers from `1` to `n`. As for `ceil`, I think it wouldn't work at the "edge" cases. It's true that the code in one line is cryptic. I suggest you see intermediate results one by one (such as `mod(bsxfun(@rdivide, (0:n^m-1).', n.^[0:m-1] ), n)` etc) to understand what the code does

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (all are bulit-in functions)

```
A = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i)(repmat(reshape(repmat(x',n^(i-1),1),[],1),n^(m-i),1)),1:m,'UniformOutput',0))
```

Explanation:

```
n = 2;
m = 4;
x = (1:n)';
A = [];
for i = 1:m
%// temp1 is (n^(i-1)) x n matrix with each row equal to x' 
    temp1 = repmat(x',n^(i-1),1); 
%// temp2 is (n^(i-1))*n x 1 column vector with corresponding elements of temp1
    temp2 = reshape(temp1,[],1);
%// temp3 is a (n^(m-i))*(n^(i-1))*n x 1, i.e n^m x 1 column vector with elements of temp2 repeated n^(m-i) times
    temp3 = repmat(temp2,n^(m-i),1);
%// A is appending temp3 into its ith column
    A = cat(2,A,temp3);
end
```

For The EDIT part:

You can do what you said i.e do `prod(B,2)` where B is a matrix calculated using above code

Comment: Not getting the desired results, could you check back again?

Comment: @Divakar I cross checked for `n=5; m=6; x= randi(10,5,1)` and my results are same as that of Luis. In you benchmarking answer you have taken `x` as a row vector while OP has taken it as a column vector and so have I. That may be the reason

Comment: Exactly that was the issue! Incorporating your results in a bit!

Comment: Congratulations! Yours is the fastest for the main question! You had my +1 already.

Comment: @Nishant, fast code, and thanks for the reply to the edit. I don't understand what the code does. Can you explain?

Comment: @DeltaIV see the explanation, feel free to ask if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [generalized truth table](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36235-generalised-truth-tables) function from the file exchange will help you

try (not tested):

```
I = ttable(n*ones(1,m));
x(I);
```

Comment: `I = ttable(n*ones(1,m));` I think.

Comment: @Divakar if you've tested it, please feel free to correct it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are tricky one-liner solutions for this. There is, however, a file on matlab file exchanging providing the solution that you are looking at if the order doesn't matter. See here [combn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn--4-3-/content/combn.m). It basically makes use of the same tricks as the one-liner presented by other answers.
If the order matters, you might have to do some sorting aftwerwards or adjust the source code directly.