# MATLAB: efficient construction of large matrices using elements of a small matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a small matrix `A` of size `(n+1)`x`(n+1)` with `n`=`O(10)`. I need to build `N=(n+1)^m` much larger matrices `B_i`, each one of size `N`x`m`, where `m`=`O(10)` also.  Luckily, I need to store just one `B_i` at the time, so memory is not an issue. To generate each `B_i` I have a matrix `I` of indices, of size `N`x`m`. `I` contains all the possible `m`-ples of integers between `1` and `n+1`. For example, let `n=4`,`m=4`, then

```
I=[1 1 1 1; 
   2 1 1 1; 
   3 1 1 1; 
   4 1 1 1; 
   5 1 1 1; 
   1 2 1 1; 
       .
       .
   5 5 5 5]
```

The indices in row `i` of `I` are the column indices in `A` of the elements of the corresponding column of `B_i`. For example, consider `i=3`, i.e., `B_3=C`. Then column `1` of matrix `C` is assembled using elements from column `3` of `A`, while columns `2` to `4` use elements from column `1` of `A`. In the same way, indices from column `j` of `I` are the row indices in `A` of the elements of column `j` of `B_i`. Consider again `B_3=C`:

```
C(1,1) = A(1,3)
C(2,1) = A(2,3)
C(3,1) = A(3,3)
C(4,1) = A(4,3)
C(5,1) = A(5,3)
C(6,1) = A(1,3)
       .
       .
C(N,1) = A(5,3)

C(1,2) = A(1,1)
C(2,2) = A(1,1)
C(3,2) = A(1,1)
C(4,2) = A(1,1)
C(5,2) = A(1,1)
C(6,2) = A(2,1)
       .
       .
C(N,2) = A(5,1)
```

And so on. It's trivial to build each `B_i` with a double for loop. However, since I have to build `N` `B_i`, the resulting triple `for` loop takes forever. Can you show me some clever MATLAB trick to build these matrices super-quickly?

By the way, I don't really need the the `B_i`, but just the elementwise product of their columns, i.e.

```
PolyMD=prod(C,2)
```

which is an `N`x`1` column vector. As I said before, I store just one `B_i` at a time, so computing `B_i` first and then `PolyMD` is not a big issue. Still, if there's a fast and simple way to get `PolyMD` directly, I'd love to know.

EDIT: here is a full example to hopefully make the question more clear.

```
% input
n=2;
m=3;
A=[1.000000000000000e+00    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.414213562373095e+00; 
   1.000000000000000e+00     1.160285448625519e-16    -7.071067811865475e-01;
   1.000000000000000e+00     1.732050807568877e+00     1.414213562373095e+00]; 
I=[     1     1     1;
        2     1     1;
        3     1     1;
        1     2     1;
        2     2     1;
        3     2     1;
        1     3     1;
        2     3     1;
        3     3     1;
        1     1     2;
        2     1     2;
        3     1     2;
        1     2     2;
        2     2     2;
        3     2     2;
        1     3     2;
        2     3     2;
        3     3     2;
        1     1     3;
        2     1     3;
        3     1     3;
        1     2     3;
        2     2     3;
        3     2     3;
        1     3     3;
        2     3     3;
        3     3     3];

% desired output for B_2 (I skip B_1 since it's trivial, and B_3,....B_27 for brevity!)    
B_2=[ -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
    -1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.160285448625519e-16     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00;
     1.732050807568877e+00     1.000000000000000e+00     1.000000000000000e+00];
```

Comment: It's not clear in your description how `B_i` differs from `B_j`. Your construction of `C` does not depend on `i`

Comment: C depends on i because the i-th row of I gives you the column indices in A. Example with B_2 and B_3: `B_2(1,1)=A(1,2)` while `B_3(1,1)=A(1,3)`, and that's because the second row of I is [2 1 1 1], while the third row is [3 1 1 1].

Comment: I think I begin to understand what you want. But if `A` is m x (n+1), so 4x5 in your example, `A((5,1)` is not defined. What's the size of `A`?

Comment: It seems like `A` has to be (at least) `(n+1)` x `(n+1)`, because for example `B_5(5,1)` is defined to be `A(5,5)`.

Comment: Sorry.@LuisMendo ! I made a typing mistake. As you correctly noticed, `A` is `(n+1)` x `(n+1)`. Need some sleep now, but tomorrow I'll check your solution and if doesn't work, I'll post a full example. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
n = 4;
m = 4;
N = (n+1)^m;
A = rand(n+1,n+1); %// example data
I = fliplr(dec2base(0:(n+1)^m-1,n+1)-'0'+1); %// combinations of column indices
for ii = 1:N %// it's better not to use "i" as a variable name
    B_i = A(bsxfun(@plus, I, (I(ii,:)-1)*(n+1))); %// linear indexing into A
    result_i = prod(B_i,2); %// "Poly" is a reserved word. Better not use it.
end
```

Comment: Hi @LuisMendo. I have already the matrix I of indices. BTW, you and others helped me generate it in [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245105/matlab-create-a-large-matrix-by-repeating-elements-of-a-vector-with-increasing). Can I skip the fifth line in your code, then?

Comment: Sure. I used that line only to generate an example for me to work with

Comment: Nope, sorry, it doesn't work. As promised, I edited my question with a  worked out example. Thanks again for the help and the patience!

Comment: @DeltaIV Try replacing `J` by `I` (see edited answer)

Comment: excellent! Now it works perfectly. I gained a 3x factor in speed (which may be even more for larger problem). Thanks a lot! Just a last question: I understand that bsxfun is used to add the row vector `(I(ii,:)-1)*(n+1)` to the matrix I. Why does this return the right elements from A? Is there a simple, intuitive explanation?

Comment: @DeltaIV `I` is the row index you want to use, whereas the column index is `I(ii,:)`. Those two indices are combined with `bsxfun` into a [linear index](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) that allows accessing the desired elements of `A`. So `bsxfun` here does the same as `sub2ind`, but it's faster for two reasons: 1) It avoids some overhead `sub2ind` has. 2) `sub2ind` would have required `I(ii,:)` to be `repmat`ted to match the size of `I`

Comment: @DeltaIV As to why I use `(I(ii,:)-1)*(n+1))`: matrix elements in Matlab are stored in [column-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). So the `(...-1)*(n+1)` when creating the linear index means "jump to another column", where `n+1` is the numer of rows

Comment: @DeltaIV Glad I explained myself! Linear indexing in Matlab is actually a very powerful tool