# MATLAB : Block diagonalize a complex antisymmetric matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I am using the following function to block diagonalize antisymmetric matrices.

```
function [R, RI , S ] = Matrix_block (A)
[U,D]= schur (A);
E=ordeig(double(D)) ;
[R, S]= ordschur (U,D, abs(E)<1000*eps ) ;
RI=R';
```

The code works perfectly fine for real antisymmetric matrices but fails for complex antisymmetric matrices as follows :-

```
a = rand(6); a = a-a'; [r,ri,s] = Matrix_block(a); 
b = rand(6)+1i*rand(6); b= b-conj(b)'; [r,ri,s] = Matrix_block(b);
```

How can I correct my code for it to work also for complex matrices ? I want a block-diagonal matrix (of the following form) as the output for both real and complex matrices.

```
     0        e1   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
    -e1        0    0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000
     0         0   -0.0000    e2        0.0000   -0.0000
     0         0       -e2   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000
     0         0         0         0   -0.0000    e3
     0         0         0         0    -e3      -0.0000
```

Comment: `b= b-conj(b)';` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab

Comment: Add some expected output for both real and complex anti-symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You need a different algorithm for the complex case. The Matlab documentation says:

> If A is complex, schur returns the complex Schur form in matrix T. The complex Schur form is upper triangular with the eigenvalues of A on the diagonal.

Also, I could notice that you cast your matrix `D` into `double(D)`. This has no real effects since `D` is already double. Nevertheless I have seen that the `ordeig` return different values for the eigenvalues depending if you input `D` or `double(D)` even for the real case. It is something to dig more deeply.