# Matlab: How to multiply sub vectors of two larger vectors?

Tags: matlab

Are there some nice way to do following.

I have 2 vectors where I want to only make sub vector multiplications. For examples,

```
a = 1:6;  b = (1:6)'
```

Then I'd like the result:

```
result = [1*1+2*2+3*3; 4*4+5*5+6*6] = [14; 77]
```

So, I'd like to multiply each sub vectors of 3 element with each others. In the end, last element of the vector `result` would then be the sum or the result of `a*b`

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as

```
sum(reshape(a,3,[]).*reshape(b,3,[])).'
```

or

```
dot(reshape(a,3,[]),reshape(b,3,[])).'
```

Comment: Think `reshape(a,3,[])` would make more sense since question says `"sub vectors of 3 element"`.

Comment: @Luis Mendo and @Divakar: THANKS! That was exactly what I was looking for. The two vectors have variable size and the same with the size of the sub vectors.
As a note, you are the first where I see `.'` and not `'` when doing a transpose :-)

Comment: `'` is _conjugate_ transpose. About `.'` versus `'`,  see [this very interesting Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922)

Comment: I know, but normally I only see people use `'`. However, I do not if the is a performance gain using `.'`, since flops is free :-)

Answer (score 2):

maybe I'm missing something, but isn't it as simple as:

```
>> [a(1:3)*b(1:3) a(4:6)*b(4:6)]
ans =

   14   77
```

??