# Construct adjacency matrix from input dataset graph file using matlab editor

Tags: matlab, graph

How can I construct adjacency matrix from input dataset graph file, which has the following data:

> The first line of the dataset file, represents the number of nodes and edges resp.
>   The following lines represent node1 and node2 denoting an edge existing between them
>   For example: amazon.graph dataset file contains the following

Below is the file amazon.graph
4 6   // number of nodes and edges
0 1   // edge between node 0 and 1
1 3
2 3
1 2
0 2
0 3

> This data is contained in a file named "amazon.graph". I need help with a  matlab function that can read the file and build adjacency matrix from the dataset file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to build the matrix:

```
x = [4 6
     0 1
     1 3
     2 3
     1 2
     0 2
     0 3]; %// data

adjMatrix = sparse(x(2:end,1)+1, x(2:end,2)+1, 1, x(1,1), x(1,2));
```

This produces a sparse matrix. You can convert to full form if needed:

```
adjMatrix = full(adjMatrix);
```

In your example, this gives

```
adjMatrix =

     0     1     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

---

To make the graph symmetric (undirected):

```
s = max(x(1,1), x(1,2)); %// take largest dimemsion
adjMatrix = sparse(x(2:end,1)+1, x(2:end,2)+1, 1, s, s); %// now matrix is square
adjMatrix = adjMatrix | adjMatrix.'; %'// apply "or" with transpose to make symmetric
adjMatrix = full(adjMatrix); %// convert to full if needed
```

---

If you have the data in a file, you can read it into the variable `x` using [`textread`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/textread.html). For example, if the file `data.txt` contains the text

```
4     6
0     1
1     3
2     3
1     2
0     2
0     3
```

just use

```
x = textread('data.txt');
```

Then you can apply the above to generate the `adjMatrix` from `x`.

Comment: Would this method work if the graph dataset file contains nodes and edges in the order of thousands ?

Comment: Also can you please tell, how to read the data from a file to build the adj matrix

Comment: Yes, the method is memory-efficient, so it works for any reasonable size. Thousands shouln't be a problem. As for how to read the data from a file, please see updated answer

Comment: One last q Luis, I wanted to ask that suppose if the graph is undirected and edge represented in the graph is such that 0 3 is present but 3 0 is not present. So how to handle this while creating the ad matrix. I know u answered this q but somehow it got lost. I apologize to ask this again . :)

Comment: I answered in a comment but it wasn't correct, so I deleted it. I have edited the answer with the correct way to to that: you build a square matrix with the largest of the two dimensions, and then apply "or" with its transpose

Comment: You are great Luis, thanks a lot.... just to confirm the third line of the code is adjMatrix = adjMatrix l adjMatrix ' ;    am i correct ?

Comment: In this case `'` and `.'` give the same result. But I prefer to use `.'` for transpose. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922)