# Using elements of a vector to set elements of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vector whose elements identify the indices (per column) that I need to set in a different matrix. Specifically, I have:

```
A = 7
    1
    2
```

and I need to create a matrix B with some number of rows of zeros, except for the elements identified by A. In other words, I want B:

```
B = zeros(10, 3); % number of rows is known; num columns = size(A)
B(A(1), 1) = 1
B(A(2), 2) = 1
B(A(3), 3) = 1
```

I would like to do this without having to write a loop.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [linear indexing](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
B = zeros(10, 3);
B(A(:).'+ (0:numel(A)-1)*size(B,1)) = 1;
```

The second line can be written equivalently with [`sub2ind`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) (may be a little slower):

```
B(sub2ind(size(B), A(:).', 1:numel(A))) = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. What does the trailing .' do in the expression A(:).' ?

Comment: It's a transpose. `A(:).'` is just `A` but making sure it's a row vector

Comment: I see -- I've been using the single quote as the transpose operator; didn't really see anyone use it with a period, so that threw me off.

Comment: That's one of my pet peeves :-) The single quote introduces a complex conjugate in addition to the tranpose. See a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922)