# Incremental matrix without loop

Tags: matlab

(Just approaching Matlab for personal understanding), suppose I have a Z,Y matrix in this case Z=1 Y=3

A=1:3

```
output: 1 2 3
```

Now I need to increase the matrix vertically to obtain:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

How can I achieve that without using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use vector multiplication.

If your goal is to obtain

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

given `A=1:3`

all you have to do is

```
A.'*A
```

This will take the vector product of the transpose (`.'`) of `A` with `A` itself

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciated.

Comment: well you explicitly wrote **transpose** - the transpose operator is `.'` - the `'` is the conjugate transpose. Though it doesn't matter in this case, its not entirely correct as it stands. [**It is just a matter of clean programming**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab).

Comment: @thewaywewalk then please accept my apologies, I never seen that difference. reinstating your edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html?refresh=true):

```
A = [1 2 3];
B = bsxfun(@times, A.', A);
```

This is essentially the same answer as Federico's where the outer product of the vector is taken.

Comment: If you benchmark, this might be the winner approach you know!

Comment: @Divakar - heh heh heh, of course you'd say that :)!

Comment: Comeon, it's not just my love for bsxfun speaking! :)