# L1 norm contour plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, contour

I am trying to plot the level set of L1 norm in matlab. But it is not at all working, and I am stuck.  Any help ?

```
x = linspace(-1,1,10);
y = linspace(-1,1,10);
[xm,ym] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sum(abs(xm-ym));
surfc(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your fourth line into this, in accordance with the [definition of L1 norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm):

```
z = abs(xm)+abs(ym);
```

You could do it more efficiently using with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to avoid generating the matrices `xm`, `ym`:

```
x = linspace(-1,1,10);
y = linspace(-1,1,10);
z = bsxfun(@plus, abs(x), abs(y).');
surfc(x,y,z)
```

Either of the two approaches produces:

[image]

For a better picture you should increase sampling, and perhaps remove surface edges:

```
x = linspace(-1,1,100);
y = linspace(-1,1,100);
z = bsxfun(@plus, abs(x), abs(y).');
surfc(x,y,z,'edgecolor','none')
```

[image]

Comment: I thought it would be z = abs(xm) - abs(ym);

Comment: @kaz A norm cannot be negative :-)

Comment: but what i see from other references, the contour is rectangular.  here is it not rectangular.

Comment: The contour is (and should be) _square_. Try `x = linspace(-1,1,100);
y = linspace(-1,1,100)` for better resolution

Comment: why do you use abs(y).' instead of abs(y)' ?. What effect does . have ?

Comment: That's one of my favourite questions :-) That's to use a _transpose_, instead of a _conjugate transpose_. See a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922)

Comment: 50K! Quite an acheivement huh! Been a long way up there :)

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! You're not that far from that :-)