# Find Nearest Location in Two Matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices:

```
A = [  76  159
      112  143
      153  159];
```

and

```
B = [  77   159
      114   143
      153   159
      173   236];
```

How can I get the nearest location with the result is the index of nearest location from another matrix without looping if possible.

For the above example, the result would look like this:

```
iA = 1 2 3;
iB = 1 2 3 3;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve here. How dus iA and iB follow from A and B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the distances between pairs of rows using [`pdist2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) (Statistics Toolbox), and then find the minimizing index along each dimension:

```
d = pdist2(A,B);     % // default is Euclidean distance. You can specify other metrics
[~, iB] = min(d);    % // arg min along each column
[~, iA] = min(d.');  %'// arg min along each row
```

If you don't have the Statistics Toolbx, you can replace `pdist2` with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to compute squared Euclidean distance:

```
d = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@minus, A, permute(B,[3 2 1])).^2, 2));
```

Comment: @Adiel http://www.offbeatoregon.com/Images/H128-hank-vaughn/ppl-390319pmo-ralph-lee-hank-vaughan-gunfight-1500.gif :-D

Comment: ooh this is what i search, sorry but can you explain how pdist2 can get the value? i dont realy understand it

Comment: oh and 1 more, what is (d.') mean?

Comment: @LuisMendo I would prefer to keep it here in SO... :))

Comment: from documentation: `D = pdist2(X,Y) returns a matrix D containing the Euclidean distances between each pair of observations`

Comment: @LuisMendo I think it would be good if you added that `pdist2` requires Statistics toolbox.

Comment: @BrilianAringga - `d.'` means to transpose the matrix `d`.  Luis Mendo will argue with you that `d.'` is the proper way to transpose a matrix over `'` :).  See a fruitful discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab

Comment: @rayryeng Exactly! :-D

Comment: @LuisMendo both results are giving different results.. could you check on that?

Comment: @SanthanSalai They give the same `iA` and `iB`. `d` in the second approach is `d.^2` in the first, to save time

Answer (score 1):

Using `bsxfun`, `permute` and calculating Euclidean distance based on native approach

This may not look elegant, but its very faster than `pdist2` for **small data sizes**

```
d = sqrt(sum((bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2]))).^2,3));

[~, iB] = min(d);    %// from Luis's answer
[~, iA] = min(d.');
```

**Bechmarking** (performed after warming up several times)

```
tic
out = sqrt(sum((bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[1 3 2]),permute(B,[3 1 2]))).^2,3));
toc

tic
d = pdist2(A,B); 
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.000080 seconds.
>   Elapsed time is 0.000453 seconds.

---

Bench Marking performed (using `timeit()`)for Different data sizes of `A` keeping Datasize of `B` constant at 20.

[image]

---

[image]

**Conclusion:**
`pdist2` is significantly efficient with large datasizes while `bsxfun`+`permute` could be used for very small data sizes.

Comment: aah, this is what i need too, thank you for help, this is helping me so much too