# Get step from size, last value and first value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, vectorization

I'm new in MATLAB and I have the following formula for the following problem. If I want to set a grey scale from 64 to 256, I just modify a matrix to create a `M[256,3]` where:

1. `M[Xi,1]=M[Xi,2]=M[xi,3]`
2. `M[Xi,Yi] < M[Xi+1,Yi]`
3. `M[1,Yi]=0`
4. `M[256,Yi]=1.`

So I need to create a matrix with steps that I don't know; the last element is `1` and the first is `0`, I got the following formula that works with any column:

```
C[i]= X0 - (Xn*i -Xn)/N
```

where `X0=0`, `Xn=1` and `N=256`.

with a loop like this:

```
k=(1:256);
for i=1:256,
   k(i)=(i-1)/255;
```

and then setting the values to the palette of colors

```
palette=zeros(256,3);

 for ii=1:3, 
     palette(:,ii)=k;
 end
```

Is there any other alternative to do is? It is really annoying using that much loops for something I think MATLAB must have: seting the values to an array based on the first element, the last element and the size of the vector.

Comment: Do you mean [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html), as in `linspace(X0,Xn,N)`? Then the answer is `repmat(linspace(X0,Xn,N)',[1 3])`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ops, didn't see your edited comment with `repmat`! Add as an answer? That must be the most intuitive solution to it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak thats the easiest solution, thanks, can you explain me the ' please?

Comment: @Divakar, thanks, I just did (for completeness). Luis: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need a vector of equidistant steps from `X0` to `Xn`, with a total number of `N` points. Exactly this can be achieved with

```
linspace(X0,Xn,N)
```

(note that this is a row vector, i.e. its `size` is `[1 N]`). The simplest way of repeating this 3 times is the `repmat` function, which repeats its first argument in a way specified by its second argument, so

```
repmat(linspace(X0,Xn,N)',[1 3])
```

will repeat `linspace(X0,Xn,N)'` (a row vector, of size `[N 1]`) three times columnwise, creating exactly the matrix (of size `[N 3]`) you need.

Note that as [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) points out in the comments to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32672360/5067311), the proper way to transpose is by `linspace(X0,Xn,N).'`, as `.'` is the transpose operator. Using simply `'` will compute the **conjugate** transpose, but as long as you're working with real numbers the two are identical (but it's easy to forget about `.'` if once you actually want to just transpose a complex variable).

Answer (score 3):

Let's [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
palette = bsxfun(@rdivide,[0:255]',255*ones(1,3))
```

---

**Explanation :** Here's how one can deduce the `bsxfun` solution starting from your original loopy approach :

1) Setup 1D Array of `i` values -

```
I=(1:256)-1
```

2) Store divisor of `255` as a row vector of `3` such elements corresponding to three columns of desired output -

```
D = 255*ones(1,3)
```

3) Finally, perform elementwise division of `I` by `D` after transposing `I` to give us our desired output -

```
out = bsxfun(@rdivide,I.',D)
```

Comment: can you please explain it ?

Comment: can you explain me the " .' "  please?

Comment: @LuisRubiera See if the edited comments add some sense?

Comment: @LuisRubiera Oh with `.'`, it is performing transpose there and not conjugate transposing with `'`. See [`Using transpose versus ctranspose in MATLAB`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab) for more info on it.

Answer (score 2):

The `gray` function does that:

```
palette = gray(256);
```

Comment: I'm not even sure it's a hack: I think OP needs a colormap. Regardless, I never would have thought of this solution:) Great job!

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! Yes, to me it's a most natural function, as it's one of the colormaps, like your beloved `jet` :-)