# Filter elements from a 3D matrix without loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 3d matrix `H(i,j,k)` with dimensions `(i=1:m,j=1:n,k=1:o)`. I will use a simple case with `m=n=o = 2`:

```
H(:,:,1) =[1 2; 3 4];
H(:,:,2) =[5 6; 7 8];
```

I want to filter this matrix and project it to an `(m,n)` matrix by selecting for each `j in 1:n` a different `k in 1:0`.

For instance, I would like to retrieve `(j,k) = {(1,2), (2,1)}`, resulting in matrix G:

```
G = [5 2; 7 4];
```

This can be achieved with a `for` loop:

```
filter = [2 1]; % meaning filter (j,k) = {(1,2), (2,1)}

for i = 1:length(filter)
    G(:,i) = squeeze(H(:,i,filter(i)));
end
```

But I'm wondering if it is possible to avoid the `for` loop via some smart indexing.

Comment: Your code does not produce your desired `G`. Which one is correct?

Comment: thank you @beaker, i have corrected the G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create all the linear indices to get such an output with the expansion needed for the first dimension with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). The implementation would look like this -

```
szH = size(H)
offset = (filter-1)*szH(1)*szH(2) + (0:numel(filter)-1)*szH(1)
out = H(bsxfun(@plus,[1:szH(1)].',offset))
```

**How does it work**

- `(filter-1)*szH(1)*szH(2)` and `(0:numel(filter)-1)*szH(1)` gets the linear indices considering only the third and second dimension elements respectively. Adding these two gives us the offset linear indices.
- Add the first dimenion linear indices `1:szH(1)` to `offset` array in elementwise fashion with `bsxfun` to give us the actual linear indices, which when indexed into `H` would be the output.

Sample run -

```
H(:,:,1) =
     1     2
     3     4
H(:,:,2) =
     5     6
     7     8
filter =
     2     1
out =
     5     2
     7     4
```

Comment: Divakar, just a question. Why do you need to use .' symbol and the squared brakets around 1:szH(1)? Is it not equivalent to simple ' and parenthesis?. Thanks.

Comment: @jruizaranguren On `.'` thing, [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25150319/3293881) might provide some good reasons. On using `[]`, yes, you can also use parenthesis, both would work.