# Diagonal matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am having trouble creating this matrix in matlab, basically I need to create a matrix that has -1 going across the center diagonal followed be 4s on the diagonal outside of that (example below). All the other values can be zero.

```
 A5 = [-1 4 0 0 0;
     4 -1 4 0 0;
     0 4 -1 4 0;
     0 0 4 -1 4;
     0 0 0 4 -1];
```

I have tried using a command `v = [4]; D = diag(v)`
but that only works for the center diagonal.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the first row of `A5`, it should be `-1 4 0 0 0`, no?

Comment: yes good catch my bad

Comment: This has been asked and answered on [math.se] http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763909/creating-a-tridiagonal-matrix-in-matlab

Comment: Consider using `spdiags` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `D = diag(u,k)` to shift `u` in `k` levels above the main diagonal, and `D = diag(u,-k)` for the opposite direction. Keep in mind that you need `u` to be in the right length of the `k` diagonal you want, so if the final matrix is n*n, the `k`'s diagonal will have only `n-abs(k)` elements.

For you case:

```
n = 5;           % the size of the matrix 
v = ones(n,1)-2;   % make the vector for the main diagonal
u = ones(n-1,1)*4; % make the vector for +1 and -1 diagonal
A5 = diag(v)+diag(u,1)+diag(u,-1) % combine everything together
```

Which gives:

```
A5 =

    -1     4     0     0     0
     4    -1     4     0     0
     0     4    -1     4     0
     0     0     4    -1     4
     0     0     0     4    -1
```

Comment: just for a complete idea how could I expand this to a 100 by 100 matrix?

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done using a [`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) matrix:

```
function out = tridiag(a,b,c,N)
% TRIDIAG generates a tri-diagonal matrix of size NxN.
% lower diagonal is a
%  main diagonal is b
% upper diagonal is c
out = toeplitz([b,a,zeros(1,N-2)],[b,c,zeros(1,N-2)]);
```

```
>> tridiag(4,-1,4,5)

ans =

    -1     4     0     0     0
     4    -1     4     0     0
     0     4    -1     4     0
     0     0     4    -1     4
     0     0     0     4    -1
```

**Note #1:** When your desired output is symmetric, you can omit the 2<sup>nd</sup> input to `toeplitz`.

**Note #2:** As the size of the matrix increases, there comes a point where it makes more sense to store it as [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), as this saves memory and improves performance (assuming your matrix is indeed *sparse*, i.e. comprised mostly of zeros, as it happens with a tridiagonal matrix). Some useful functions are [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html), [`sptoeplitz`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13353-sparse-toeplitz-matrix-construction)<sup><sub><sup>FEX</sup></sub></sup> and [`blktridiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10603--block--tri-diagonal-matrices)<sup><sub><sup>FEX</sup></sub></sup>.

Answer (score 4):

A little hackish, but here it goes:

```
N = 7; % matrix size
v = [11 22 33]; % row vector containing the diagonal values
w = [0 v(end:-1:1)];
result = w(max(numel(v)+1-abs(bsxfun(@minus, 1:N, (1:N).')),1))
```

This gives

```
result =
    11    22    33     0     0     0     0
    22    11    22    33     0     0     0
    33    22    11    22    33     0     0
     0    33    22    11    22    33     0
     0     0    33    22    11    22    33
     0     0     0    33    22    11    22
     0     0     0     0    33    22    11
```

To understand how it works, see some intermediate steps:

```
>> abs(bsxfun(@minus, 1:N, (1:N).'))
ans =
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1     0     1     2     3     4     5
     2     1     0     1     2     3     4
     3     2     1     0     1     2     3
     4     3     2     1     0     1     2
     5     4     3     2     1     0     1
     6     5     4     3     2     1     0

>> max(numel(v)+1-abs(bsxfun(@minus, 1:N, (1:N).')),1)
ans =
     4     3     2     1     1     1     1
     3     4     3     2     1     1     1
     2     3     4     3     2     1     1
     1     2     3     4     3     2     1
     1     1     2     3     4     3     2
     1     1     1     2     3     4     3
     1     1     1     1     2     3     4
```

Comment: Nice ;-) I think you have a spare `.` in `bsxfun(@minus, 1:N, (1:N).')`

Comment: @EBH I prefer to [leave that dot there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922) :-)