# Matlab Syntax Help .'*

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

I am currently using the Eigen library to convert some Matlab code to c++.
I have been given the matlab code and it's as follows:

I have 2 Matrices `N_R`, `G_R`.

`N_R` is a 8 row 10 col matrix while

`G_R` is a diagonal matrix of an 8 value vector

There is a system matrix that has the term `N_R .' * G_R * N_R` in it.

I am having real trouble with this term and haven't been able to find what this combination of `. ' *` actually does.

I'm guessing it's some kind of transpose and multiply but I keep getting errors about the dimensions being mismatched.

Comment: `N_R . ' * G_R * N_R` is not valid MATLAB syntax. I almost felt sorry for your confusion.

Comment: @AndrasDeak. Well, the only problem with it is the space between . and ', and that may be an editorial issue.

Comment: @Johan I agree. But here's my train of thought: "Oh, basic syntax question, answered by 10k user, *bah*." --> "Oh, is *that* how the MATLAB code was written? Diabolical, who would do such a thing? Poor OP." --> "Waaaait a minute, that's not even valid MATLAB syntax. So why is somebody asking for syntax not even using the syntax they're asking about?". (I admit my grumpiness might have been effected by complications with SO Docs)

Answer (score 4):

The `'` operator in matlab is performing matrix conjugate, while `.'` performs a simple transposition, as explained at [Using transpose versus ctranspose in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab). Note that `. '` is not valid, but `.'` is.

```
N_R.' * G_R * N_R
```

would with [Eigen (Tutorial Matrix Arithmetic)](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html) be

```
N_R.transpose() * G_R * N_R
```

(*Thanks @Dev-iL for pointing out that I swapped the two meanings in the original version of the answer*)

Answer (score 3):

As you said, `.'` is the *transpose* operator (notice: it does not contain spaces) in MATLAB, while `*` is *matrix multiplication*.

Now, let's review the rest (I took the liberty to put parentheses for clarity):

```matlab
(N_R.') * (G_R) * (N_R)
```

- `N_R` is 8x10, so `N_R`<sup>T</sup> is 10x8.
- `(N_R.') * (G_R)` is 10x8 * 8x8, so 10x8.
- `(N_R.') * (G_R) * N_R` is therefore 10x8 * 8x10, so 10x10.