# Extract Digits From Matlab String

Tags: regex, matlab

In Matlab, let's say that I have the following string:

```
mystring = 'sdfkdsgoeskjgk elkr jtk34s ;3k54352642 643l j3kf p35j535';
```

And I want to extract all the digits in it to a vector such that each digit is standing by its own, so the output should be like:

```
output = [3 4 3 5 4 3 5 2 6 4 2....]
```

I tried to do it using this code and regex:

```
mystring = 'sdfkdsgoeskjgk elkr jtk34s ;3k54352642 643l j3kf p35j535';
digits = regexp(mystring, '[0-9]');
disp(digits);
```

But it gives me some weird 4-combined digits instead of what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the output of `regexp` is in the *index* of the first character in each match which is why the numbers aren't the same as the digits in your string. You'll want to use the output of `regexp` to then index into the initial string to get the digits themselves

```
digits = mystring(regexp(mystring, '[0-9]'));
```

You will still need to convert these from characters to numbers so you can subtract off `'0'` to do this conversion

```
digits = mystring(regexp(mystring, '[0-9]')) - '0';
```

Alternately, you could specify the `'match'` input to `regexp` to return the actual matching string itself. This will return a cell array which we can then convert to an array of numbers using `str2double`

```
digits = str2double(regexp(mystring, '[0-9]', 'match'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I use transposing instead of any other existing function to convert a string into an array.

```
mystring = 'sdfkdsgoeskjgk elkr jtk34s ;3k54352642 643l j3kf p35j535';
digits   = regexp(mystring, '[0-9]');

array    = double(mystring(digits)')'-48;    % array of doubles
disp(array);
```

Comment: `'` is [not the transpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab). Also, the transposes are completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Suever Doesn't `A'` give transpose of `A` in this case as has been asked in the question? I have just given a solution which had worked for me some time ago, and this solution would also work for the question of asker. Yet, you have my +1 for giving a better solution than me.

Comment: It's best to always use `.'` because that will work regardless of the input format so that it yields a reliable transpose. The transpose trick I think you're trying to use here would be if you used `str2num`: `str2num(mystring(digits).')`

Comment: @Suever I had tried my own solution in MATLAB before I posted, it worked fine, so that's why I have shared. There is always a better solution. Thanks for sharing extra information. Best regards.

Comment: Right but you don't need the transpose at all: `mystring(digits) - 48`

Comment: @Suever I have just noticed that `'` was truly unnecessary in this case since output is already an array. But when there is a string like `s='1234'` and if we would like to split these integers into an array such as `[1,2,3,4]`, I am using this transposing trick as `n = (str2num(s'))'`. That is why I used transposing in my asnwer. When it comes to strings, it converts it to double as `1234`.