# Using sinc interpolation in MATLAB for complex vector

Tags: matlab, interpolation, complex-numbers

I am using sinc interpolation for complex sinusoid. It is working fine for real part, but the imaginary part seems inverted.

```
t1=0:pi/10:2*pi;       % sample points
s1=exp(1i*t1);         % sampled signal
figure(1),subplot 211, plot(t1,real(s1),'o');
subplot 212, plot(t1,imag(s1),'o');

t2=linspace(0,2*pi,100);   % interpolation points, a total of 100.

[T2,T1]=ndgrid(t2,t1);

s2=sinc((T2-T1)*10/pi)*s1'; 

figure(1),subplot 211, hold on, plot(t2,real(s2),'.');
subplot 212, hold on, plot(t2,imag(s2),'.');
```

[image: Blue circle: sample values; Red dots: interpolated values]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `s1'` ([conjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html)) when you actually want `s1.'` ([transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html)).

This is a common mistake. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922).