# How can I force a variable in matlab to be a column vector

Tags: matlab

See the below code:

```
clc;
clear;


%rng('default')
t = 1900;
u  = randn(t+100,1);
e  = randn(t+100,1);
ep = randn(t+100,1);
A = 0; 
x=zeros(t+100,1);
for iii = 1:5000

   for i=2:t+100 
      x(i) = 0.99*x(i-1)+u(i);
      u(i) = 0.5*u(i-1)+e(i);
      ep(i)=0.99*u(i);
      y(i) = A*x(i-1)+ep(i);

end
```

`y` is a `1 x 2000` but I want to be a `2000 x 1`, I used `y'` but this doesnt seem to work when I perform later operations on y. My MATLAB seems to flip between a `1 x 2000` and a `2000 x 1`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the semi colon operator to ensure that `y` will be a column vector: `y = y(:)`. Also noticed that `'` is the conjugate transpose operator, you probably want to use `.'`. More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150027/using-transpose-versus-ctranspose-in-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: you are missing an `end` for the second `for` loop. I am not sure what the `iii` loop is doing anyway because `iii` is not used anywhere.

Second, and to answer your question, you can (and probably should) pre-allocate your variables before your loop. This will not only allow you to specify whether each variable is a row or column vector, but it will also improve the speed and efficiency of your code.

So, corrected version would be:

```
clc;
clear;

%rng('default')
t = 1900;
u  = randn(t+100,1);
e  = randn(t+100,1);
ep = randn(t+100,1);
A = 0; 
x = zeros(t+100,1);
y = zeros(size(x));

for i=2:t+100

   x(i) = 0.99*x(i-1)+u(i);
   u(i) = 0.5*u(i-1)+e(i);
   ep(i)=0.99*u(i);
   y(i) = A*x(i-1)+ep(i);

end
```

And just to check `y` is of the correct size after running the code:

```
>> whos y
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        y        2000x1                      16000  double

Total is 2000 elements using 16000 bytes
```