# Creating Indicator matrix based on vector with group IDs

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a vector of group IDs:

```
groups = [ 1 ; 1; 2; 2; 3];
```

which I want to use to create a matrix consisting of 1's in case the i-th and the j-th element are in the same group, and 0 otherwise. Currently I do this as follows:

```
n = size(groups, 1);
indMatrix = zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        indMatrix(i,j) = groups(i) == groups(j);
    end  
end
indMatrix

indMatrix =

 1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     0     1
```

Is there a better solution avoiding the nasty double for-loop? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done quite easily using [implicit singleton expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), for R2016b or later:

```
indMatrix = groups==groups.';
```

For MATLAB versions before R2016b you need [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to achieve singleton expansion:

```
indMatrix = bsxfun(@eq, groups, groups.');
```

Comment: What's the role of adding the extra '.' after groups? Seems to work also without.

Comment: @bonifaz Good question! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25150027/2586922)